# Reading / copying datagridview rows when another thread may come in to update them?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

In my winforms app, I have an existing datagridview.  There's a background worker that fetches data from a database and refreshes that datagridview's contents once every minute.

OK, now I have a child form in that app.  When the user presses a button, I want to pop up another child form to the user, showing them a datagridview that is an exact copy of the first one, so that they may select a single row.

(NOTE: The main form/app has quite a few tabs. I have thought about instead using a column of checkboxes on the first datagridview, in cooperation with the first child-form's button, in order to accomplish this.  But I think this method I'm working on will make life easier for the users.)

To quickly grab a copy of all of the rows of the first dgv, I was going to do this:

```
        DataGridViewRowCollection rawrowcollection = null;
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
             rawrowcollection = ParentForm.dgvIncidentTimeline.Rows;
        }));
```

(And then, I'd check to see if the resulting collection was null... loop through the collection so as to create/ populate a List... and then loop through that to populate the second/fresh datagridview.)

My only concern is that... what if I try to read from that table and it's in the middle of doing its once-per-minute clearing-and-updating of that datagridview?   Granted, this should be a very FAST process.   And we're doing a read here, which I don't think would PREVENT the clearing/updating from occurring (would it?)    But we could end up with partial data in the final dgv.

I thought about temporarily setting the parent dgv to readonly before doing the read...and then setting it back after doing the read.  ??    And then I'd have to just plan on my once-per-minute background operation possibly throwing an exception if it tries to clear and update while we've got that dgv effectively "locked" like this??

Your thoughts??

Thanks!

Comment: Don't keep data in the control. Create a model to hold data, then you can access it from anywhere without hassle. Add some events to rise when data are changed so that any current view (form with `DataGridView`) can update itself.

Comment: I'd still have to somehow "lock" the data from updating in the middle of a read... or from being read in the middle of an update, wouldn't I?

Comment: as long as you are using thread sage objects in your data model like concurrent bag then you should be fine.  Note that data objects like a generic list are not thread safe.